# Objective-C / Cocoa: How do I revert a window (and all controls on it) to Interface Builder defaults?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib

I got a Window with several controls and labels loaded from xib. 
At runtime some label titles are set and some buttons are disabled.
I want to revert everything to the state where the program started.

I can do this like:

```
[button setTitle:@"Start"];
[button setEnabled:@"YES"];
myLabel.stringValue = str;
```

etc.

I rather revert the whole Window to the xib values.
How can this be done?

Comment: Save the initial settings in `NSUserDefaults`, and then restore them from there when needed.

Comment: Thanx Koen, but the initial settings are already saved in the .xib and I am looking to restore these. Mabe this is the second best option.

Comment: Some ideas: 1. Bind the labels and buttons to properties and reset the properties. 2. Set the initial settings in code instead of in the XIB. 3. Close the window and reload from the XIB. 4. Load an invisible window from the XIB and compare.

Comment: Thanx, I will start from here: User Defaults and Bindings [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/NSUserDefaultsController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid)

Comment: If you bind to `NSUserDefaults`, the defaults will change with everything you change.